expect script inside bash doing remote ssh /etc/sudoers replacement
I am having issues with the below script.  I am trying to replace a line in /etc/sudoers file but need to do it using sudo and either input my password or as in example here, put it in a variable.
#!/bin/bash
#
pw=“P@ssword!20@$”
#
while IFS= read -r host
do
  echo "$host"
  ping -c1 "$host" > /dev/null 2>&1
  returncode=$?
    if [ $returncode -ne 0 ]
      then
        echo "$host is not reachable";echo
      else
        echo "ping successful on $host"
        echo "modifying /etc/sudoers file now"
        sleep 3
        export host
        expect <<'EOF'
        spawn ssh -t myuserid@$env(host) "sudo -S su - myuserid -c sed -i ‘/myuserid ALL=(ALL) ALL/c\myuserid ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL/ /etc/sudoers'"
        expect "\[sudo] password for myuserid:”
        send "$env(pw)\n"
        expct eof
EOF

    fi
done < serverlist.txt

The output I get is:

ping successful on myserver.example.com modifying /etc/sudoers file now
spawn ssh -t myuserid@myserver.example.com sudo -S su - myuserid -c
sed -i '/myuserid ALL=(ALL) ALL/c\myuserid ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL/
/etc/sudoers' [sudo] password for myuserid: no such variable
(read trace on "env(pw)")
invoked from within "send "$env(pw)\n""

thank you for your help!!!

You didn't export pw

Your script has a "pretty" quote after myuserid:”. Replace it with the proper quote sign.

hi Gerald, can you be more specific?  should it be single quotes?  Thank you

Thanks Glenn. added export pw and fixed expct eof to expect eof

hi, when I run the script again, I am now getting below error:
[sudo] password for myuserid: su: invalid option -- 'i' Try 'su --help' for more information. Connection to  myserver.example.com closed.
thank you again.

Btw.: If you insert a syntax error into /etc/sudoers, nobody can use sudo anymore.

Thanks Cyrus, will take that into account, I have tested the sed command locally on the host and it works fine, now just trying to wrap in a script. but thanks for the warning!!

About the quotes: What are curly quotes and can I use them in my code?.

hi Kamil, how does this help me?  thanks.

@john, this line expect "\[sudo] password for myuserid:” contains only one double quote. This breaks the rest of the expect part.

su's -c option take one single string. The argument to -c is the word sed. You have to enclose the sed command in quotes in order to give it to the -c option. That puts you firmly in quoting hell. The solution is to simply remove -c -- su works fine without it: sudo -S su - myuserid sed -i ...

hi Glenn,
this line 'expect "[sudo] password for myuserid:” contains only one double quote.` can you let me know how I need to modify it to get it working.
thank you again.

” is different than "; so is “. In the code you posted there is also ‘, it is different than '. Under the link I gave you there is an answer that correctly states: "In programming languages however, these quotes are not interchangeable. Straight quotes are often special characters that perform specific functions within the language while the similar looking curly quotes are not recognized as special. Instead, they may produce errors, or they may be treated as ordinary characters somewhat similarly to letters."

@kamil, gotta ya, thanks.

@glenn, can you help me fix that issue you identified.  Seems that is the last piece to get this working.  thank you

which one? su? I offered a solution for it.

@glennjackman, I belive you said there was an issue with this expect "\[sudo] password for myuserid:” You indicated that you only see one double quote and that it's breaking rest of the expect part.  so, should there be another quote that I'm missing?

The character after myuserid: is not a plain ASCII double quote, it is a
unicode "RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK" -- https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/quotes.html -- What editor do you use to write code?

@glenn, thanks Glenn, I use vim on macos (version 9.0.2142)

If you're still waiting for a reply, I don't think the comments could be more clear. You have a bad character that you need to fix.
